# How to integrate iMessage onto address book?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I have to send a text from my app to the contacts present in the contact list. I can do that using AddressBook and its delegates. How can i roll everything into iMessage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create and display an `MFMessageComposeViewController` and configure it with the phone numbers or email addresses you've obtained from the Address Book. Whether they're sent as iMessages or SMS messages is an implementation detail as far as you, the developer, is concerned.

[MFMessageComposeViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thanks for the ans bro, I'd like to know whats that implementation detail. As of now, I'm done with this MFMessage thing.